# How does make pass 'VPATH' to the sub-make

Tags: makefile, vpath

**Thanks a lot for the comments. In this case actually `VPATH` is not used.**

I write some makefiles to recursively build my project.

Part of the **makefile** in the root directory looks like this,

```
VPATH += $(shell find -type d)
export VPATH

#Codes to generate $(ARXIVS), i.e. the list of all local archives,
#is omitted here to save spaces
all : main.o $(ARXIVS)

$(ARXIVS) :
           $(MAKE) --directory $(@D)

.PHONY : $(ARXIVS) all
```

As you can see, I pass the variable `VPATH` to sub-**make**s, in order to save some computational cost. And the whole system works.

But the searching paths in a sub-directory is different from the ones in the root directory.

I have print the values of VAPTH in sub-**make**s, the paths are indeed the ones with respect to the root directory. So VPATH in the sub-**make**s should be wrong.

But the whole system works. How did this happen?Any one give the suggestion to me. Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe it works because VPATH isn't even needed? The command `find -type d` doesn't work because there is no directory specified. If it works on your system, does it output *absolute* pathnames?

Comment: Ah, I made a mistake. You are right. VPATH is not used. Secondly, the command `find -type d` does work. And the result is not absolute pathnames. In my case, the `find` command searches in the current directory.

Comment: `find -type d` works if you're using GNU find; in GNU find if there's no value given as the first argument then `.` is assumed.  In BSD find (for example, if you're using MacOS) then you have to explicitly type the `.` (I find this very annoying).